# Balls and bins, with cardinality constraints

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, enumerative-combinatorics

Suppose I have $n$ sets of $k$ balls each, with each one of the $nk$ balls distributed uniformly at random among $m$ bins.  Further suppose that I have a probability vector $p=(p_1,\dots,p_m)$.  I am interested in selecting one ball from each of the $n$ sets, such that each bin $i$ contains roughly $p_i n$ selected balls.  Is there an asymptotic expression for the number of ways this can be done, in the limit as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: So you distribute the $nk$ balls and then try to select one per set to match $p$?

Comment: @BrianHopkins yes, correct.

Comment: How do the other quantities depend on $n$? Are you keeping $k$, $m$, and $p$ constant as you take $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @SamZbarsky yes, everything else is fixed, and we can assume that $k\ll m$ if we want.

Comment: What "roughly" means? The answer may significantly depend on how one defines "roughly" here.